# With PHP, Can I POST Directly to Text File?

Tags: php, forms, file, post, text

I know that the usual method for handling a form with PHP is to POST to a script like this:

```
echo("<form action='handleForm.php' method='post'>");
```

it possible to POST *directly* into a text file like this:

```
echo("<form action='formData.txt' method='post'>");
```

?

Comment: What does "POST directly into a text file" mean? You can send a POST request to a url that ends with `formData.txt`, there is no problem with that. You have already done that in your second snippet.

Comment: No. It ain't possible.

Comment: @mario: it **is** possible. You can send a `POST` request to any valid url. `formData.txt` is a valid relative address.

Comment: Short answer: No.

Long answer:
Yes, but it won't do what you want it to. The result of "posting" to a text file when on a web browser, will simply display the contents of the text file.

Comment: Do you mean you want to take the input and append it to a text file?

Comment: @zerkms From the question I find it somewhat unlikely that OP has set up an action/method handler for that.

Comment: @mario: indeed, but let's teach them what HTTP is and how to ask properly :-)

Comment: Before you all get into the details whether or not it can be done, you should make sure you know what "it" is that should be done. The one half is right that you can POST to any valid URL you want, and the other half is right that there won't be any magic effects like automatically append the posted data to the text file. And the third half is right that you can nontheless add some magic rewriting and scripting that allows to POST to that "txt" URL and on the server append to that file. This however is pretty close to just use the PHP script and let it do the work.

Comment: @Marty Yes, that's in essence what I wanted to do. Currently, I'm POSTing to another php file that writes to a file. I'm really new to php and coding in general and was wondering if I could cut that step out.

Comment: Oh I see, unfortunately you can't do that. The PHP step is necessary as it is where the instructions on how to perform that task occur. This is the whole point of having PHP.

Comment: @everyone Thanks for taking the time to comment. I know this is super basic but that's where I am and every thing I can pick up helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append the text into the file, it won't.

POST is a type of request to the server to send data. HTTP server will answer with your `txt` file, and the browser will show that. As the server as default is not able to run any kind of txt codes, nothing will happen. You can set up different codes, how to handle these files.

There are a lot of types of request, read further if you interested in.